# How to change values based on the selection from the drop-down list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, html-select

In my drop-down list, I have selection 1(A) and selection 2(B). If I select A from the drop-down list, I want to see a name, Janifer. If I select B, I want to see another name, David.

```
var mylist = document.getElementById("mylist");

if (mylist.value == "1") {
    document.getElementById('myalllist').getElementsByTagName('option')[1].selected = 'selected';
}
if (mylist.value == "2") {
    document.getElementById('myalllist').getElementsByTagName('option')[2].selected = 'selected';
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="mylist" onchange="fndropoption()">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>

<select id="myalllist" onchange="fndropoption()">
    <option value="1">xxxxxxxx</option>
    <option value="2">yyyyyyyy</option>
</select>
```

Comment: set "selected" attribute of all other options to empty string then, do the `selected="selected"` line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46892115/how-to-show-different-selected-value-than-options-label

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work with onChange attribute either.  This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var foo=document.getElementById("mylist"); 
    foo.onchange=function() {
        if(foo.options.selectedIndex != 0) {
            document.getElementById("myalllist").options.selectedIndex = foo.options.selectedIndex-1;
        }
    }

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="mylist">
 <option value="0" selected="selected">Select</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
</select>       

<select id="myalllist" onChange="">
 <option value="1">xxxxxxxx</option> 
 <option value="2">yyyyyyyy</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this - the onchange should be on the first dropdown list - to trigger the change for the second list. Seems to work, eg: selecting 3 in the first list causes the selection of 3 in the second list.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<select id="list1" onChange="changeList()">
 <option value="0" selected="selected">Select</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
</select>       

<select id="list2" >
<option value="0">0</option>
 <option value="1">1</option> 
 <option value="2">2</option> 
 <option value="3">3</option> 
 <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<script>
function changeList() 
    {
        var selectedOption=document.getElementById("list1").options.selectedIndex; 
        document.getElementById("list2").options.selectedIndex = selectedOption;

        var selectedOption2=document.getElementById("list2").options.selectedIndex; 
        console.log(selectedOption2) 
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if i just want to see value=0 in list 2 when i select value= 0 in list1...n so on don't i have to use options[0].selectedIndex

Comment: it was already doing that - i just didn't have the "0" listed in the select option text, but the value was 0. Note that I have amended the code above and added it in. I also added a console.log mechanism to demonstrate the value listed on each change of list1. When you change it to option 2 in list 1, list 2 will change to show option 2 and the console.log will show a 2. and so on. If you change it to "0" in list1, you get "0" in list2 and "0" in the console. Try changing the list1 with the console open and you will see the changed value of list2